# How can I change my Mii so that it changes on other people's 3DS's as well?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

My sister created my Mii in my stead. I tried changing it's appearance and name, and it looked like it worked by looking on my own 3DS, but on my friend's it's still the same. Is the problem on my end, and how can I fix it if it is?

Comment: On what application on your friend's 3DS was it not changed?

Comment: Your friend may have to connect to the internet to get it updated...always a possibility, not sure how this one works

Comment: If you are talking about Streetpass Plaza Miis, then you would have to Streetpass with your friend again for them to get the updated Mii.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to your Mii's appearance on your friend's Streetpass Plaza, then you would need to Streetpass with your friend again for it to update.

If you are talking about the "Friends" application on the 3DS, your Mii should update on your friend's 3DS automatically with an internet connection.

Comment: If OP is talking about streetpass, he also needs to start Streetpass Plaza at least once to update his Mii's appearance there, or the Mii in the plaza will still be the old one.

Answer (score 0):

It should do it automatically, if not then you would have to change your mii manually on the 3ds.